Vite throws error: Could not resolve "subscriptions-transport-ws"
I'm migrating an existing react app from create-react-app to vite. After the basic setup, I ran "npm start" and received the error below:
[ERROR] Could not resolve "subscriptions-transport-ws"

    node_modules/@apollo/client/link/ws/ws.cjs:6:39:
      6 │ var subscriptionsTransportWs = require('subscriptions-transport-ws');
        ╵                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "subscriptions-transport-ws" as external to exclude it from the        
  bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can    
  also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time  
  instead of bundle-time.

As you can see, the line of code that required "subscription-transport-ws" is in node_modules and I'm not supposed to change it. My @apollo/client library is the latest version "^3.10.4". I know "subscription-transport-ws" is deprecated. I don't understand why it is still required in the latest @apollo/client.
How can I get rid of this error and get my app running with Vite?
Thank you in advance!
I tried to install "subscription-transport-ws" manually. The build succeeded but my app was not really running. It only shows a blank page. The console showed the error below:
 Uncaught (in promise) 
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js


The "ws" was from "subscription-transport-ws" I just installed.

